# Xamarin Studio (Xamarin.iOS) not including build number on archive?

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Since updating my Mac to XCode 8 (For iOS 10 support) Xamarin Studio is not including the Build # in archives.  In the Archives window the build number (Code column) is empty, then when uploading the IPA to our Enterprise app store we get an error saying the Build # is invalid.

Has anyone else run into this issue since upgrading?  I've tried restarting Xcode, Xamarin and the Mac itself with no luck.

[image]

[image: Missing build # in Xamarin after updating to XCode 8]

Comment: Can you include your version information in your post? In Xamarin Studio, version information can be obtained by navigating to: Xamarin Studio -> About Xamarin Studio -> Show Details -> Copy Information button (on Mac) or Help -> About -> Show Details -> Copy Information button (on Windows) and the log files can be found from Help -> Open Log Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being unrelated to my recent XCode update.  Rather, we had previously pushed a version "0.2.1" which equates to "21" in our EMM solution (it ignores 0's).  I'm not sure if the same can be said about the App store.  So version 1.0.1 = 11, which is less than 21 thus the build # error.  I'm not sure why Xamarin no longer shows the build # in the Archive screen but it ended up not being related to the problem we were having.